# Working with Text Files Two

Tags: c, io, fopen, fclose

A couple of questions really about the code below from which I gained assistance in a previous post.

1). Any ideas why at the end of the ouput, I get a random garbage character printed? I am freeing the files etc and checking for EOF.

2). The idea is that it can work with multiple file arguements, so I want to create new file names which increment, i.e. out[i].txt, is that possible in C?

The code itself takes a file containing words all separated by spaces, like a book for example, then loops through, and replaces each space with a \n so that it forms a list, please find the code below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

FILE *fpIn, *fpOut;
int i;
char c;
while(argc--) {
    for(i = 1; i <= argc; i++) {
        fpIn = fopen(argv[i], "rb");
        fpOut= fopen("tmp.out", "wb");
        while (c != EOF) {
            c = fgetc(fpIn);
            if (isspace(c)) 
                c = '\n';
            fputc(c, fpOut );
        }
    }
}
fclose(fpIn);
fclose(fpOut);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Its not actually, I'm putting together a collection of word lists for Network Testing purposes, and figured running some books through this little program would create some nifty lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reach the end of file, you don't `break` the loop. So you are calling `fputc(c, fpOut);` with `c==EOF` which is probably an undefined behavior, or at least the writing of a `\0xff` byte.

And you don't call `fclose` inside your `while(argc--)` loop, so your files (except the last) are mostly never closed nor flushed.

At last, you don't test the result of `fopen` and you should test that it is non null (and print an error message, perhaps with something about `strerror(errno)` or `perror`, in that case).

You should have found out with a debugger (like `gdb` on Linux), and perhaps with the help of compiler warnings (but `gcc-4.6 -Wall` did not caught any bugs on your example).

You could decide that the output file name is related to input file name, perhaps with

```
char outname[512];
for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
   fpIn = fopen(argv[i], "rb");
   if (!fpIn) { perror (argv[i]); exit(1); };
   memset (outname, 0, sizeof (outname));
   snprintf (outname, sizeof(outname)-1, "%s~%d.out", argv[i], i);
   fpOut= fopen(outname, "wb");
   if (!fpOut) { perror (outname); exit(1); };
   /// etc...
   fclose(fpIn);
   fclose(fpOut);
   fpIn = fpOut = NULL;
}
```

Comment: That aside, any ideas for Q1 in my description, thanks for the above, it was most helpful :)

Comment: Your garbage character is probably the `\0xff` I mentioned. On my machine, it probably is ÿ; and not `fflush`-ing or `fclose`-ing files make the output truncated arbitrarily.

Comment: Whoopsie, I meant to say Q2,  you already gave a great answer to 1 in your reply :)

Comment: I edited my reply to answer to Q2, which I did not understood entirely (I am only guessing what you probably mean).

Comment: You don't need to zero-out `outname` if you're just going to call `snprintf` on the buffer anyway. Also, `snprintf` expects the size of the buffer, not the size of a writeable buffer (it will write to at most `n-1` of the string, saving the last byte for the null character).

Comment: The `memset` is not useless. It ensures the last byte is `\0` = the zero byte to terminate strings (even when `snprintf` don't have enough space) because I required `snprintf` to not consume all of the `outname` ! And it is much safer.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Why not just set the last byte then, rather than all of them? There is no need to set them *all* to zero if `snprintf` is going to write over them anyway. Also, `snprintf` always ensures the output is null-terminated by only writing to at most `n - 1` characters. That is, if you have a buffer of size 5, it will write at most 4 bytes and save the last byte for the null character.

Comment: Agreed. Actually, I forgot that `snprintf` always add a zero bytes (while `strncpy` don't), even when reaching the maximal size.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested changes (all untested):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int 
main(int argc, char** argv) {

  FILE *fpIn, *fpOut;
  int i;
  char c;
  for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    fpIn = fopen(argv[i], "rb");
    if (!fpIn) {
      perror ("Unable to open input file");
      continue;
     }
    fpOut= fopen("tmp.out", "wb");
    if (!fpOut) {
      perror ("Unable to open output file");
      fclose (fpIn);
      continue;
     }
     while ((c = fgetc (fpIn)) != EOF)) {
       if (isspace(c)) 
         c = '\n';
       fputc(c, fpOut );
     }
     fclose(fpIn);
     fclose(fpOut);
  }
  return 0;
}
```