# C - Working with fopen, fclose, fputc etc

Tags: c, file-io, io, fopen, fclose

I've got this code finally working with a single argument on my command line, i.e. one file for it to work with, although I designed the code with the concept of it working with an unlimited number of files. What it does is take some X number of text files containing words separated by spaces, and replaces spaces with `\n` thus creating a list of words. Though, it successfully completes the first argument, it just ignores the 2nd.

Another minor problem seems that it also prints out some garbage letter at the end, a Y with two dots above it; I assume some EOF symbol, yet I can't seem to stop that happening!

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE *fpIn, *fpOut;
    int i, j;
    j = 1;
    char c;
    char myString[256];

    printf("%d", argc);
    printf("\n");
    printf("The following arguments were passed to main(): ");
                for(i=1; i<argc; i++) printf("%s ", argv[i]);
    printf("\n");

    while(argc--) {
        for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            fpIn = fopen(argv[j], "rb");
            snprintf(myString, 256, "%s~[%d]", argv[j], i);
            fpOut= fopen(myString, "wb");
            while (c != EOF) {
                c = fgetc(fpIn);
                if (isspace(c)) 
                    c = '\n';
                fputc(c, fpOut );
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Working with Text Files Two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649068/working-with-text-files-two). Your accepted answer on that question explains why you're getting that extra garbage character. Your code continues to be incorrect in this question.

Comment: Yep that was my previous post, I've made some progress though, but usually dont get responses on older posts, so I thought I could make another :)

Comment: I don't really understand why, if Im honest

Comment: In short, consider the rule: *Never write the `EOF` value to a file.* Now, how might that happen in your code? (It does, you'll have to figure out how and fix it.)

Comment: I still cant seem to get it working for multiple arguments though :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getchar()`, `getc()` and `fgetc()` functions (or macros) return an `int`, not a `char`.

You must use:

```
int c;

while ((c = fgetc(fpIn)) != EOF)
{
    if (isspace(c))
        c = '\n';
    fputc(c, fpOut);
}
```

Think about it; the functions must be able to return any valid `char` *and* EOF (which is distinct from any valid `char` value.  So, by definition, the return value can't be a `char`...

What happens if you use `char`?

- Your original code didn't initialize `c` before testing it (so the loop might break early).
- Your code didn't test `c` immediately after reading EOF (so it might print a garbage character, often ÿ, LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS, U+00FF).
- If your `char` type is unsigned, you'd never see EOF.
- If your `char` type is signed, some valid characters (often ÿ again)) will be misinterpreted as EOF.

---

> I still can't seem to get it working for multiple arguments though.

The problem there is the double loop you have running:

```
int i, j;
j = 1;

while (argc--)
{
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        fpIn = fopen(argv[j], "rb");
        ...process fpIn...
        j++;
    }
}
```

Let us suppose you invoke the command with two file names; then `argc == 3`.

After the first time past the `while` loop, `argc == 2`.  You then do a `for` loop with `i` taking the value 1; you open `argv[1]` (because `j == 1`).  You process that file; then increment `j` to 2, before also incrementing `i`, also to 2.  The second time around the `for` loop, `i` == 2 as does `argc`, so the `for` loop terminates.  The while loop decrements `argc` again to 1, but tests that `2 != 0`.  However, the `for` loop sets `i = 1` and then terminates because `i == argc`.  The `while` loop decrements `argc` to 1, and repeats.

You can use a `while` loop or a `for` loop, but you don't need both.

So, either:

```
for (i = i; i < argc; i++)
{
    ...process argv[i]...
}
```

Or:

```
while (--argc > 0)
{
    ...process *++argv...
}
```

I'd use the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks, I added a check to see whether it was EOF within my current loop, if ( c == EOF) {break;} That fixed it!

Comment: I still cant seem to get it working for multiple arguments though :/